# Fitting a polynomial regression in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

It is easy to use linear regression to fit some data, but is there a way to find the best curve fitting 3 or more points with a polynomial line?

Here's my expected outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a polynomial regression with **numpy**'s [`polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```py
import numpy as np

n = 2
z = np.polyfit(x, y, n) # Expects `x` as 1d array
quadratic_regressor = np.poly1d(z)
```

or with **SKLearn**'s `preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures`:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

n = 2
quadratic_regressor = Pipeline([('pf', PolynomialFeatures(n)), 
                                ('clf', LinearRegression())])
quadratic_regressor.fit(x, y) # Expects `x` as 2d array
```

---

Example:

```py
x = [0, 1,2]
y = [10,0,1]
plt.scatter(x,y)

x_ = np.linspace(-1,4)
plt.plot(x_, quadratic_regressor(x_)) # Numpy
```

```py
plt.plot(x_, quadratic_regressor.predict(x_.reshape(-1,1))) # SKLearn
```

[image]